# How to find largest $\lambda$ where $1- \lambda^{n}(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n} \geq \lambda x $ holds for all $n$?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to find the largest $\lambda$ where  $$1- \lambda^{n}(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n} \geq \lambda x $$ holds for all integers $n\geq 1$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$. I did a grid search and it is somewhere around $\lambda^* \in [0.82, 0.83]$, but I am not sure if it is possible to calculate it in closed form.

I faced the inequality when proving the approximation ratio of a randomised approximation algorithm. More specifically, it's a sub lemma of Exercise 5.8 in designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf.

Comment: $n=1$ is trivially true. It seems at $n=2$, the solution is $\lambda = 2(\sqrt{2}-1)\approx 0.828$. Not sure how (or if) to generalise this for $n>3$.

Comment: @AspringMat: Anyways, would you mind adding context to your question? Because your question doesn't really meet the Quality Standards of MSE, which will attract alot of downvotes.

Comment: As a matter of respecting new Quality Standards Enforcement, I have to delete my answer for now until your question is updated.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen That's very respectful, not so many people here behave like this, they rather take the opportunity to give an answer to get upvotes.

Comment: @Nicolas: Thank you, I'm just doing my part, same as you, to make MSE better :).

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen I faced the inequality when proving the approximation ratio of a randomised approximation algorithm. More specifically, it's a sub lemma of Exercise 5.8 in https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf. 

I already came up with the Linear Program + Bounded the cost function with the LHS. I only need to bound it with the RHS to show it is a $\lambda$ approximation. 

This isn't homework, not sure if this is otherwise needed context or not.

Comment: @AspiringMat: I'm sorry if I was annoying to you somehow. You can check my answer below.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen No worries and thanks for the answer! I do understand it seemed like a homework question, but it was just because I tried to "separate" it from the problem I was solving as much as possible. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have the good guess.

---

By choosing $n=2$ and $x=1$, we see that $\lambda$ has to be smaller than or equal to $2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. 
Now we will prove that $\lambda=2(\sqrt{2}-1)$ is also a value for which your initial inequality is true.
Firstly, by our choice of $\lambda$, we see that the following inequality is true for $n=1,2$
$$1 \ge \lambda + \lambda^n(1-\frac{1}{n})^n \quad (*)$$
For $n \ge 2$, you see that indeed, $n \mapsto  \lambda^n(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ is a decreasing with $\lambda =2(\sqrt{2}-1)$. So because $(*)$ is true for $n=2$, we imply that it is true for all $n$.
Now in the last step, to prove that $1 \ge \lambda x + \lambda^n(1-\frac{x}{n})^n $ for all $n \ge 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$, you can use the observation that the RHS is a convex function on $x$, so its maximum is achieved at either $x=0$ or $x=1$. But,
$$RHS_{x=0}= \lambda^n \le 1 \quad \text{(true)}$$
and $$RHS_{x=1} = \lambda+(1-\frac{1}{n})^n\lambda^n \le 1 \quad \text{(true)}$$
So in conclusion, $\lambda= 2(\sqrt{2}-1)$ is the maximum value of $\lambda$ such that :

$$1 \ge \lambda x + \lambda^n(1-\frac{x}{n})^n $$ for all $n \ge 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$